# LaTeX beamer class: Words are completely broken

Tags: pdf, latex, beamer, texmaker

The following LaTeX code gives me a completely broken pdf file, where words are totally random broken.

```
\documentclass[12pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

%\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}

\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%beamer settings:
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\title{Homomorphic Encryption - Paillier Encryption}
\date{21.06.2022}
\author{Name 1\\Name 2}

\begin{document}
\frame {
    \titlepage
}
\section{Definitionen}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Pre - Fully Homomorphic Encryption}
\begin{definition}[Fully Homomorphic Encryption]
% Quelle: https://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2010/3/76275-technical-perspective-a-first-glimpse-of-cryptographys-holy-grail/fulltext
Eine eine homomorphe Verschlüsselung ist eine FHE, wenn auf dem Ciphertext jedwege mathematische Operationen ausgeführt werden können.
\end{definition}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[See resulting image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Bdw8.png)

The words are fixed again, if I use one of the beamer templates. But I don't want to use one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem is the very classic problem solver: **I did an update and rebooted.**
After that the problem was fixed.
I still don't understand why the error was there, but stumbled across a related problem. There the solution also was an update.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).